# How to delete records using update strategy for the target not having PK informatica?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

How to delete records using update strategy for the target not having PK informatica?

1. Set PK in target definition in Informatica even-though if DB doesn't have PK. I am not sure, whether it will work or not.
2. Create mapping only for delete and in the session property set "treat target rows as" to Delete and choose target table property to "Delete".

Comment: See, how beautiful is your question now. [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) is the improvement, what you really need.

Answer (score 0):

You can set PK in the target definition. It should work.

Comment: If target table  doesn't have a PK or index, it will impact the performance right? I guess it's not a advisable approach

Comment: Right, it is not. If you plan to delete  a lot of records, better define primary key at the DB level.

Answer (score 0):

You can define primary key on your Target definition. or you can write target override query if you want to update or delete based on non key values.